# How do I set a target layer in the Editor Toolbar?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers

I am using ArcMap 10.4 and have not been able to figure out how to set a target layer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It may be as simple as right clicking on your "Parcels" layer and select Selection > Make This The Only Selectable Layer.  My understanding is that "Parcels" is the target layer and by making it the only selectable layer.

There are other instances where making a layer the "Target" layer, such as the Select By Location tool. But in the instructions you've provided, I think they want to make sure that the "Parcel" layer is the only one selected.

Answer (score 1):

There is a custom tool in ArcMap called "Target Layer" and am gathering that whoever wrote the directions had that in their toolbar.
[image: Target Layer tool]

You can add that into your toolbar by going to:

1. Customize
2. Customize Mode...
3. Commands tab
4. Categories: Editor
5. Commands: Target Layer
6. Drag the little Tile/Pencil icon up into your toolbar somewhere. When you release the mouse, the dropdown menu will appear. This is an old-school UI that has largely been replaced by the 10.x editing enhancements but it still has its use and good to know it's there.

[image: Target Layer tool added]

Once added, you can close out of your Customize windows and use the Target Layer tool.

[image]

There are some other cool tools hiding in Customize Mode as well! Explore away!

Answer (score 0):

In 10.5, I do not see an option to set the layer to edit within the Editor toolbar. Perhaps the instructions are for a prior version. In 10.5, as soon as "Start Editing" is selected it will prompt you to choose which layer to edit.